# Postfix & Rails 3.0 ActionMailer: lost connection after STARTTLS

Tags: email, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, postfix-mta

I'm using Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.0.4 in development mode and I'm trying to configure it to send emails from the Postfix server installed on the same box (Running Ubuntu 10.04 with the dovecot-postfix package installed)  Whenever I attempt to send an email from Rails, it goes through cleanly in Rails but displays an error in the Postfix logs (I've removed domains and IPs from the excerpt below):

```
Feb 21 04:49:16 alpha postfix/smtpd[9060]: connect from alpha.mydomain.com[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
Feb 21 04:49:16 alpha postfix/smtpd[9060]: lost connection after STARTTLS from alpha.mydomain.com[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
Feb 21 04:49:16 alpha postfix/smtpd[9060]: disconnect from alpha.mydomain.com[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
```

The strange part is that when I connect to the SMTP server from an email client like Thunderbird, it works with no problems.

I know development mode sometimes doesn't allow for sending emails so I added the following to the environments/development.rb file:

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true

 #load mail server settings
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "mail.mydomain.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => 'mydomain.com',
  :user_name            => 'username',
  :password             => 'password',
  :authentication       => 'plain',
  :tls  => true,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true  }
```

Comment: I've done some more digging and enabled greater verbosity in Postfix logs.  I'm now seeing the logs showing "503 5.5.1 Error: authentication not enabled" yet I have enabled SASL in the postfix configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that your certificate is not valid, and that Thunderbird falls back to plain SMTP when sending emails? Try disabling TLS in your config.

Comment: I disabled TLS for both smtp and smtpd in Postfix's main.cf and then removed the :tls line from the rails config and changed :enabled_starttls_auto to false.  Now I've getting "lost connection after AUTH"

Comment: Maybe you don't have permission to connect to the server from your IP, which might be localhost (127.0.0.1)? Check your main.cf Postfix configuration file maybe.

Comment: I managed to fix it using this: http://davidroetzel.wordpress.com/2011/01/14/rails-3-actionmailer-tls-certificate-verification/ I never even knew that option existed from reading some of the ActionMailer docs.  Turns out there is a problem with the SSL cert it was using.

Answer (score 11):

If you're just sending email from localhost, then you don't need SMTP and all the authentication issues that come with it. You can simply deliver with sendmail directly.

`config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail`